Is there a way to detect if a mixin content block expect parameters? i.e. the mixin was included with `using (...)`?
I wanted to be able to @include a mixin with or without the using (...) clause, used to accept arguments in the @content block, as per documentation.
.my-simple-selector {
    @include my-mixin using ($parent) {
        #{$parent}.some-complex-selector:not(&) {
            property: value;
        }
    }

}

and
.another-selector {
    @include my-mixin {
        property: value;
    }
}

for a mixin declared like so:
@mixin my-mixin {
    $parent: &;

    @at-root .complex-selector {
        @if (<has using (...)>) { // detection here.
          @content($parent);
        } @else {
          #{$parent} & {
            @content;
          }
        }
    }
}

